# Using a base object in forEach JavaScript loop

Tags: javascript

I have a JS array of objects, each object holds a series of variables I'm using to populate a HighCharts chart, such as a name and the data scores. It's the same chart, but the series changes for each person. So I'm trying to use a base HighCharts object and just loop through the data. But I'm finding that my base object is just appended to, and isn't really a base. This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kw79ens8/12/) demonstrates the problem. I've tried using `const` and `let` and seen that I can do `Object.create()` and the object will belong to `proto`. But I also saw that this was deprecated. I'm sure this is fairly simple, but I haven't figured it out yet.

Looking at the output, the first chart is correct.
`{attending:"Mr A", data:[1,2,3]},` is used as the series.
The second chart should show 1 series called `Mr B` with the data points `[8,9,10]`.

When it actually shows 2 series, the first 1 (Mr A) and the second one.

Comment: Sorry but yuor question isn't very clear, what is your expected jsfiddle output ?

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini Updated the Q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are experiencing is because of the pass-by-reference design in Javascript. You are mutating your 'highchartBase' object inside of your loop. Therefore each subsequent chart will have the previous series properties as they are all pushed to the list.

You can solve your problem by doing a deep clone of the 'highchartBase' object:

```
  var chart = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(highchartBase));
```

or you can recreate the object in the loop each time like [Mosè Raguzzini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1234087/mos%C3%A8-raguzzini) 's answer:

```
var chart = {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'A Title'
    },
    series: []
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the deep clone solved my problem. I need to reuse the chart object, so I have to have the chart object outside of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

In JS the `objects` and `arrays` are passed by references. Thats the reason why in the second chart `B` gets appended to `A`. A simple fix would be to clone the object using JSON parse and stringify methods.

`var chart = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(highchartBase));`

Answer (score 0):

Don't have the time to investigate when object is modified by hicharts, a simple fix

```js
series.forEach(function(e) {
 var parent = document.getElementById('base');
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  var id = e.attending.replace(/([^a-z0-9]+)/gi, '-');
  div.setAttribute('id', id);
  parent.append(div);
  var chart =  {
chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'A Title'
    },
    series: []
};
  chart.series.push( 
   {name: e.attending, data: e.data, color: '#808387'} 
  );
  Highcharts.chart(div, chart);
});
```